# Is this system design ok for a VPN service for 3000 users?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, vpn, openvpn

I am setting up a vpn service for 3000 users in AWS. The solution is built up on Linux and AWS. The design of the solution is:

[image: Architecture]

My questions is:

Am I missing something critical in the design I have presented in the above diagram?

Comment: Your first question is an off-topic product recommendation style question, as for the others: although all related to your project each question is a separate question by itself on a separate topic and typically you'll get better answers if you don't combine multiple topics in a single question.  Regardless ServerFault likes people who have done their homework and are struggling with an actual problem. For example in your question 2, show that you have read the ELB documentation, ideally set it up and if and when it doesn't work as intended, then come back.

Comment: Thanks HB,

I will take your advice, and remove the improper / unnecessary questions. I will come back with each question separately later, when I am dealing with it specifically.

For now, I will leave it with just one question.

Comment: Many websites will be inaccessible, because they block AWS IP addresses due to many years of abuse.

Comment: Michael, could you suggest a remedy for this situation?

Comment: If I just need to provide malware blocking and hosts filtering to my users, then are my needs better served with a dns server? How could I control access to the service?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing bad on that. The diagram is a little complicated, but otherwise... if the load balancer can scale to 3000 concurrent connections, then this should work nicely.

Comment: If I just need to provide malware blocking and hosts filtering to my users, then are my needs better served with a dns server? How could I control access to the service?